# Generating ROW_NUMBER() with partition in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, row-number

I have a query in `T-SQL` which contains partition by clause and based on the ROWNumber generated i want to pull on 2 things:

1. Results having more than one record (probably taking the latest from the parition clause)
2. Pulling first record from the above point (point #1).

Here's my T-SQL query which i want to convert into EF:

```
select * from 
(
select StudentId, ProgramId, StudentProgramTaggingId, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By StudentId, ProgramId order by StudentProgramTaggingId) as RowNum 
from MahadStudentProgramHistory
group by StudentId, ProgramId, StudentProgramTaggingId
)a where a.RowNum > 1
```

Here's what i tried in EF to get the desired results:

```
var studentPrograms = db.StudentProgramHistories;
                var groupByStudents = studentPrograms
                    .GroupBy(x => new
                    {
                        x.StudentId,
                        x.ProgramId
                    })
                    .Select(x => x.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

The above EF code pulls all the records skipping duplicates, however i want the opposite, i want to get the first record from the duplicates and ignore all orders which are singles.

Comment: You can't, and what you tried doesn't use ROW_NUMBER(). EF Core is the wrong query for this job - run reporting queries. ORMs are meant to map entities to tables, and there are no entities involved here. *LINQ* over EF allows you to write far more complex queries than you can with other ORMs, but you still can't reproduce every SQL query and function with it.

Comment: You could create a view that executes the inner query and map to it, or use Dapper to execute the raw query directly

Comment: On the other hand, what you are doing is essentially selecting `MIN(StudentId), MIN(ProgramId), StudentProgramTaggingId`. Or rather, the `MIN(ProgramID)` for the student with the smallest `StudentID`. Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and its working. Maybe you don't want to use this because of the ToList function.

```
var studentPrograms = db.StudentProgramHistories
        .ToList() // this may slow
        .Select((s, i) => new { Row = s, Idx = i + 1 })
        .Where(w => w.Idx > 1)
        .Select(s => s.Row)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: ToList will put everything from StudentProgramHistories into memory and would be really slow